# Unable to locate words in phrases in text files using python

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I am trying to locate words and phrases contained in multiple text files.  My code will locate the words but it is completely missing the phrases.  Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this?  Regular expressions may taker too long given that I have several thousand txt files.

My code is as follows.

````
import glob


work_list = ['at least', 'from time to time', 'in effect', 'greater than', 'lower than', 
'more than', 'up to', 'approximate', 'approximately', 'at the same time']

path = 'D:/Testing10'


context_d = {} # this will be used later 
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    # if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        f = open(filename)
        file = f.read()
        txt = file.lower()
        txt = txt.split()
        txt = [item.replace('May', '') for item in txt] # locate and replace all months of May before lowering
        txt = [item.replace('\n', '') for item in txt]
        txt = [item.replace('\\n', '') for item in txt]
        txt = [item.replace('\\', '') for item in txt]
        txt = [item.replace('\\s', '') for item in txt]
        y = range(len(work_list))
        for i in y:
            if work_list[i] in txt:
              print(work_list[i], "found in filename", filename)
            else:
              print("not found")```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through your work_list and look in the text file without chopping up the text file into words and phrases, assuming that the text file contains one continuous piece of text.  You may have to eliminate line returns if you have any in your text file:

```
work_list = ['at least', 'from time to time', 'in effect', 'greater than', 'lower than',
'more than', 'up to', 'approximate', 'approximately', 'at the same time']

path = 'D:/Testing10'

context_d = {} # this will be used later
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    # if filename.endswith('.txt'):
    f = open(filename)
    file = f.read()
    txt = file.lower()
    for element in work_list:
        if element in file:
            print(f'"{element}" found in file {filename}')

#Sample output:

"at least" found in file data_files/sample.txt
"from time to time" found in file data_files/sample.txt
"greater than" found in file data_files/sample.txt
"lower than" found in file data_files/sample.txt
"up to" found in file data_files/sample.txt
"approximate" found in file data_files/sample.txt
```

Comment: Works nicely, thanks.  I may need to keep the string split as I need to find tri-grams either side of the word/phrase (hence the context_d dictionary which I commented)

Comment: The problem with splitting the string initially is that you lose your ability to find phrases and will be limited to words again. Once you have found the phrases and words, then you can split the string on them to find adjacent words or use other tactics.